# getting the last event data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an external jquery plugin (iosSlider. but it doesn't metter). The plugin triggers an event when I click the mouse and move it. The plugin triggers the event and supply data to the listener. But, it doesn't provide the original event object. The original event object contains data which I don't have in the data the plugin supplied. Is there any way I can get the data of the last event happend?

Comment: you should try to put it in a method calling the callback nope?

Comment: @Ispuk: What to put in a method? My callback function, the one that catch the event, gets as parameter only the data the plugin provides me. The plugin use custom event but regular event trggered it.

Comment: you should document better your answer, paste some code we will check what to do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the plugin source, find the code where the "original event" is transformed into the "watered-down" version that you are getting, and add the original event to the watered-down one as an additional field.

Before:

```
handleOriginalEvent(e) {
    // ...
    var wateredDownEvent = { /*...*/ };
    // call event handler with wateredDownEvent
}
```

After

```
handleOriginalEvent(e) {
    // ...
    var wateredDownEvent = { /*...*/, original: e };
    // call event handler with wateredDownEvent, now with added original event
}
```

Comment: I was trying to prevent from dugging in those 2000 lines of JavaScript and searching all the places calling the event. But, I think this is the only way I can solve it. Thanks.